# untabify on save in Emacs 24 without make-local-hook

Tags: emacs

I'd like to untabify whenever I save a buffer. This worked fine until I upgraded to Emacs 24 which broke it, as there is no `make-local-hook` anymore. Have a look:

```
;;; untabify on C-x C-s (except for GNUmakefiles that needs tabs)
;;;   (note: `stringp` check to avoid bug (?) in HTML-mode)
(defun untab-all ()
  (unless (and (stringp mode-name)
               (string= mode-name "GNUmakefile") )
    (untabify (point-min) (point-max)) ))

;; TODO: doesn't work anymore as no make-local-hook in Emacs 24 - 
;; it won't work with simply dropping that line,
;; or doing that, and passing a 4th `t` argument in the second
;; add-hook call (which is the LOCAL parameter)

;; (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
;;    '(lambda ()
;;       (make-local-hook 'write-contents-hooks)
;;       (add-hook 'write-contents-hooks 'untab-all) ))
```

**EDIT**

Got it to work with the below help and [this](http://ocikbapps.uzh.ch/gc3wiki/ikiwiki.cgi?page=blog%2FWhitespace_cleanup_with_Emacs&do=getsource) site.

Ironic thing is, with my old solution (using `make-local-hook`), somehow I got this **globally** (which is why I had to add that check for GNU makefiles).

Now, this seems to be a local thing: this is good as that check needn't be done at every save; only, you have to state for what modes untabify should be done. (I guess you could just add them one by one as you go along, every time you discover a tab, until you're done. Although it feels like you're using 5-6 modes, when you think about it, you use tons!)

But, to confuse things even more, the HTML mode seems to do this, with no intervention! If you read the code above, you see that even for the old solution, HTML was the cat among the ermines...

Anyway, this seems to work:

```
(defun untab-all ()
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
   nil ) ; did not write buffer to disk

(defun add-write-contents-hooks-hook ()
  (add-hook
   'write-contents-hooks
   'untab-all
     nil  ; APPEND  unrelated, explicit default nil as optional :)
     t )) ; LOCAL   non-nil => make hook local

;; more modes: http://www.emacswiki.org/CategoryModes
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook   #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook         #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook       #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
(add-hook 'sql-mode-hook        #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
(add-hook 'css-mode-hook        #'add-write-contents-hooks-hook)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emacs 24 uses the `LOCAL` parameter of `add-hook` instead of `make-local-hook`.  (I believe that was added in Emacs 21.1, but `make-local-hook` wasn't removed until Emacs 24.)

Try this:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
    '(lambda ()
       (add-hook 'write-contents-hooks 'untab-all nil t) ))
```

Your other problem is that `untab-all` must return `nil` to indicate that it did not write the buffer to disk (as explained in the docs for `write-contents-hooks`, or as it's now called, `write-contents-functions`):

```
(defun untab-all ()
  (unless (and (stringp mode-name)
               (string= mode-name "GNUmakefile") )
    (untabify (point-min) (point-max)) )
  nil) ; did not write buffer to disk
```

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, and I say so above. It doesn't work: When I save, it gets stuck saving. If you can solve this, it'd be a lifesaver!

Comment: This is why you shouldn't just say "it doesn't work", but instead explain what happened and what you expected to happen.  You were asking about `make-local-hook`, but your real problem had nothing to do with that.

Comment: 1. The title reads "untabify on save in Emacs 24 without make-local-hook" - is it not clear, what I seek? 2. I didn't "just say 'it doesn't work'" 3. While there might be an "other problem", this other problem is related as it worked fine until I upgraded Emacs.